Triples (a,b,c) of natural numbers for which a² + b² ± ab = c². Triangles with an angle 60º or 120º
The Law of Cosines states:
$c² = a² + b² - 2ab \cos(\gamma)$.  For  $\gamma = 60º$  or  $\gamma = 120º$,  this becomes:
$c² = a² + b² ± ab$
I used ChatGPT to find such numbers for $0 < a < b < 61$  and obtained the following:
$(m,n,k):  \gamma = 60º: m² + n² − m⋅n = k²$
(3,8,7), (5,8,7), (5,21,19), (6,16,14),
(7,15,13), (7,40,37), (8,15,13), (9,24,21),
(10,16,14), (10,42,38), (11,35,31), (12,32,28),
(13,48,43), (14,30,26), (15,24,21), (15,40,35), (16,21,19), (16,30,26),
(16,55,49), (18,48,42), (20,32,28), (21,45,39), (21,56,49), (24,35,31), (24,45,39), (25,40,35), (28,60,52), (30,48,42), (32,42,38), (32,60,52),
(33,40,37), (35,48,43), (35,56,49), (39,55,49).
$(m,n,k):  \gamma = 120º: m² + n² + m⋅n = k²$
(3,5,7), (5,16,19), (6,10,14), (7,8,13), (7,33,37), (9,15,21),
(9,56,61), (10,32,38), (11,24,31), (12,20,28), (13,35,43), (14,16,26),
(15,25,35), (15,48,57), (16,39,49), (18,30,42), (21,24,39), (21,35,49),
(22,48,62), (24,40,56), (27,45,63), (28,32,52), (30,50,70), (32,45,67),
(33,55,77), (35,40,65), (36,60,84), (40,51,79), (42,48 78), (49,56,91),
(55,57,97)
I also found a connection between triples for  $\gamma = 60º$  and  $\gamma = 120º$  as shown in my video:    https://youtu.be/cVFaZThhKHE
However, I wasn't able to find a formula to compute the triples similar to the formula from Euclid for Pythagorean Triples.

Welcome to Math SE. See Eisenstein triple.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the related Determine all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+b^2+ab$ is a perfect square. & Pseudo-pythagorean theorem, while a site search comes up with "Eisenstein triples" shows Issues generating all primitive integer triangles with 60 degree angle (Eisenstein Triples).
